# Insert null values into SQL Server database from datagridview cell changed

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, insert, null

I want to insert/update some values from a datagrid with cell changed event. It is not problem when values are entered correctly but if user don't enter any values it is necessary to send null to db columns. My codes like in below and you can see what I try. Maybe it is simple but I haven't wrote codes for so many years.

Thank you

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        conn.Open();

    id = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

    string nikadi = (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value == null) ? "NULL" : dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    string niuygadi = (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value == null) ? "NULL" : dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    string niuygdty = (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value == null) ? "NULL" : dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    string niuygytk = (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value == null) ? "NULL" : dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();

    if (id == "")
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        /* cmd.CommandText = "insert into mytable (nikadi,niuygulamaadi,niuygulamadetay,niuygulamayetkisi) values ('"
                + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "','" 
                + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "','" 
                + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "','" 
                + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString() + "')";*/
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into mytable (nikadi, niuygulamaadi, niuygulamadetay, niuygulamayetkisi) values ('"
               + nikadi + "','"
               + niuygadi + "','"
               + niuygdty + "','"
               + niuygytk + "')";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        gridyetki();
        MessageBox.Show("Insert operation Done");
    }
    else
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "update mytable set nikadi='"
                + nikadi
                + "',niuygulamaadi='" + niuygadi 
                + "',niuygulamadetay='" + niuygdty
                + "',niuygulamayetkisi='" + niuygytk
                + "' where ID='" + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        gridyetki();
    }

    conn.Close();  
}
```

Comment: If you start to use parameters your life will be better (and your code as well)

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Program has a front login screen and users are limited person who don't need to try injection. For now the easy solution is going with cell value change event so can you give an opinion in this position thank you.